# Context unique to each group at a specified level

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend, mathematica-7

Recent versions of Mathematica provide the option of having a unique `$Context` for each cell group, via:

- Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to Each Cell Group

This is an appealing concept, but I find it unusable, as my code spans multiple cell groups.

I would like a way to specify a unique context for cell groups *of a certain level* such as every `Section`, but *not* a separate context for every `Subsection` or `Subsubsection`.

A solution will need to affect new cell groups as they are created.

Comment: could you perhaps describe some possible uses for these cell contexts?

Comment: @magma the Help itself is a good example.  By having Context Unique to Each Cell Group, you can (for the most part) safely evaluate the examples without them interfering with each other, or your own Notebooks.  I would like to be able to to have similar behavior in my own Notebooks that address a collection of related yet contextually independent topics or problems, while preserving the ability to organize the code for these topics using Subsection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by modifying your notebook's stylesheet. You can use the option `CellContext` to set the context. The mma documentation does this to restrict example context to Cell groups.

Comment: But which cell groups?  Are you saying I can affect cell groups ***only*** down to a certain level, ***without*** affecting that level's subgroups?

Comment: If you do "CellContext->"yourNameHere"<>ToString[SectionNumber]<>"backtick" in the definition of the Input cell I believe it should work. The only problem is getting at SectionNumber as for all I know the section number lurks in a `CounterBox["Section"]` element and I'm not sure how to extract the number from that.

Comment: Sjoerd, you too, please upload a Notebook or stylesheet that is set up in this manner.

Comment: @mr.wizard You missed the subtle phrasing of my answer: "You should be able to..." ;-). But I'm working on it (now and then), main problem is getting the section number. I've a question out on that one.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for spending your time on it!

Comment: @mr.wizard I know I can get the context at the section level, as I have done this manually, by setting this CellContext to a unique name for all input cells in a section. The easiest way to automatically get a unique name for each section would be using its section counter. But this appears to be an elusive beast.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by grouping cells manually instead of relying upon the automatic grouping mechanism.  In the notebook in question, use the menu item *Cell* / *Grouping* / *Manual Grouping* to enable manual grouping.  Now, as you enter sections, subsections, etc. they will not be grouped automatically.  Select the cells that you wish to be in a single group and use the menu item *Cell* / *Grouping* / *Group Cells/Group Together*.  Now that they are grouped, you can set the *CellContext* to be *CellGroup* and they will all play well together.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do what I want (I just tried it), and manual grouping is a mess.

Comment: WReach, would you please upload a Notebook file that you have set up as you believe I want?  Two people voted for this, so either it works for them, or they do not understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please take a look at [this notebook](http://members.shaw.ca/weaklyreachable/so/grouping-woes.nb).  Note that my answer does not fully meet your needs as manual intervention is needed for new cell groups.